Limit rigid body constraints to adjacent objects
I'm trying to model a rockfall with rigid body constraints (Object->Rigid body->Connect), but by the end of the simulation I am left with this weird shell of objects that are bound together by constraints but that have space in between.
What has happened is that the connections between those objects are still intact, but the force of the impacts further upslope has knocked out the objects that used to sit between them.
I think the solution to this would be to only connect objects that are adjacent or within a certain radius of each other, but I'm not sure how to do this. Does anyone know if it is possible?

